# Infinite scroll slow to load new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using [infinite scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) to load new content / images into the index of a wordpress theme via ajax.

This site is **live** at : **http://mylife.holstee.com/**

Here's the code that I'm using, it's deep in [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) and it's minified so you won't be able to see find it yourself.

```
$container.infinitescroll({
        nextSelector: "#mylife-quinary .next-link a",
        navSelector: "#mylife-quinary .next-link",
        itemSelector: "#mylife-quaternary .item"
    }, function( newElements ) {
        mylife.quote();
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });;
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
            $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems );
        });
    }
);

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.item',
        columnWidth : $(".item").outerWidth(true)
    });
});
```

What I want is a much smoother interface, so that you don't have to wait for the new content. *Any ideas?*

Comment: Either the images are taking too long to load, or the content is. Use your browser's console to figure out which it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [www.infinite-scroll.com](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/):

```
element.infinitescroll({
// ...
  bufferPx : 40,
    // increase this number if you want infscroll to fire quicker
    // (a high number means a user will not see the loading message)
    // new in 1.2
    // default: 40
// ...
});
```